# LDAP- ldap.add does not add entries to the LDAP server

Tags: ruby, database, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I'm very new to working with LDAP, and any help is appreciated.

I'm writing a Ruby program that adds entries to an LDAP server. I'm able to add entries just fine using Terminal. But the challenge is getting it to work using Ruby.

Here is the LDAP server I'm trying to write to.

```
# example.org
dn: dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: Example Inc.
dc: example

# admin, example.org
dn: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator
userPassword: mypassword

# people, example.org
dn: ou=people,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: people
```

And here are the contents of ldap-program.rb. For the

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'net/ldap'

    ldap = Net::LDAP.new  :host => '127.0.0.1',
                            :port => 1300,
                            :auth => {
                                :method => :simple,
                                :username => 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org',
                                :password => 'mypassword'
    }

  dn = "uid=christine,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com"
attr = {
  :cn => "Christine",
  :sn => "Smith",
  :objectClass => "inetOrgPerson",
  :mail => "christine@example.com",
  :uid => "christine"
}

ldap.add(:dn => dn, :attr => attr)
```

I've been following the documentation for ldap.add very closely, but in this case the entry does not get added to LDAP. Can anyone give any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: Could you please describe the error you are getting back?

Comment: Maybe a separate ldap.auth is required, See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271834/ruby-net-ldap-add-user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby net-ldap add user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271834/ruby-net-ldap-add-user)

Comment: Just to note .... as the naming attribute is 'uid' ,you don't need to add it as attribute as well.

Comment: You tagged `active-directory`. Are you actually using AD? If so, you have a few problems that I can see.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yes, I believe so. I'm extremely new to LDAP so I am also trying to figure out how exactly it works too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Ruby developer, so my code examples may need tweaks. But if you are using Active Directory, then I see two problems:

1. The `objectClass` should be `user`
2. In AD, the [`uid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-uid) attribute has no special meaning. The username used for login is the [`sAMAccountName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-samaccountname) attribute.

```
attr = {
  :cn => "Christine",
  :sn => "Smith",
  :objectClass => "user",
  :mail => "christine@example.com",
  :sAMAccountName => "christine"
}
```

You may also want to set [`givenName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-givenname), which is for the user's first name.

If that doesn't work, let us know what error you are getting.

That will create the account in a disabled state. To enable it you need to give it a password in a second step by setting the [`unicodePwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-unicodepwd) attribute (which has a weird format), and updating the [`userAccountControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-useraccountcontrol) attribute to enable it.

Modify it again, using these attributes (where the new password is `"new_password"`):

```
def self.str2unicodePwd(str)
    ('"' + str + '"').encode("utf-16le").force_encoding("utf-8")
end

attr = {
  :unicodePwd, str2unicodePwd("new_password"),
  :userAccountControl, 0x200
}
```

I borrowed some code from [here](https://blog.bronislavrobenek.com/post/80163028550/changing-password-in-activedirectory-using-ruby) for the password bit.